# How to store Session variables over more than 2 pages?

Tags: php, html, forms, session

I have a multipage form and i want to save all my form inserts in a session that I could save them after clicking the submit button in my last formpage in my database.

**Question 1:**
Do I have save every form variable to a session variable like this?
I mean do i have to store the variables from last page on the current page as here in the example? Will this work or is there a possibility to store them more easy?

**Page1:**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>form1</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="form2.php">
    <p><input type="text" name="sname"> Name</p>
    <p><input type="text" name="semail_address"> Email</p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="form 2"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Page2:**

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['sname'];
$_SESSION['email_address'] = $_POST['semail_address'];
?>
<form method="post" action="form3.php">
   <p><input type="radio" value="Free" checked="checked"name="smembership_type">Free</p>
   <p><input type="radio" name="smembership_type" value="Normal">Normal</p>
   <p><input type="radio" name="smembership_type" value="Deluxe">Deluxe</p>
   <p><input type="checkbox" name="sterms_and_conditions">I agreee</p>
   <input type="submit" value="Form 3"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Page 3:**

```
<?php
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['membership_type'] = $_POST['smembership_type'];
 $_SESSION['terms_and_conditions'] = $_POST['sterms_and_conditions'];
 ?>
```

....

**Question 2:**
And then how do i save them into database? Is the syntax right?

```
$query = "INSERT into subscriptions(name,email_address,membership_type,terms_and_conditions,name_on_card, credit_card_number, credit_card_expiration_date)".
    "VALUES(" . $_SESSION['name'] . ", 
            " . $_SESSION['email_address'] . ",
            " . $_SESSION['membership_type'] . ",
            " . $_SESSION['terms_and_conditions'] . ",
            " . $_SESSION['name_on_card'] . ",
            " . $_SESSION['credit_card_number'] . ",
            " . $_SESSION['credit_card_expiration_date'] . ")";
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is correct we can use sessions like that.But its not good practice to do like this. Better create forms in the same page.Show the first page on page load and hide the others(Display none). Instead of the submit button in the first use a normal button and give a jquery on click to show the second form on button click.Try this code.

```
       <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>form1</title>
        <style>
         #secondForm{
           display:none;
         }
        </style> 
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>     
         <script>
         function display(formName){
             if(formName=='first'){
                $('#firstForm').css("display","block");
                $('#secondForm').css("display","none");
             }else{
                $('#firstForm').css("display","none");
                $('#secondForm').css("display","block");                 
             }
         }
         </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <form method="post" action="">
            <div id="firstForm">
            <p><input type="text" name="sname"> Name</p>
            <p><input type="text" name="semail_address"> Email</p>
            <p><input type="button" value="Next" onclick="display('second')"></p>
    </div>
            <div id="secondForm">
            <p><input type="text" name="sname"> Name</p>
            <p><input type="text" name="semail_address"> Email</p>
            <p><input type="button" value="Previous" onclick="display('first')"></p>
            <p><input type="submit" value="Save"></p>
    </div>
        </form>
        <?php 
        if($_POST){
            //save code sql
        }
        ?>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

no session is not the good idea
u just could do update the database for each page with the current page form data wich i mean update the database with the current page form data and pass the success to the next page as a post method

Answer (score -2):

If you are using a submit button to send the information to the server for validation or any other business logic so that you can make decision regarding the next page loading, then yes.

If not, then why use, Submit? You can very well have this form in a div which is shown for the users when page 2 & 3 have forms in hidden div blocks. Instead of Submit you can have a button, say with label "Next", on clicking you can hide the current div and show the div (currently in Page 2) and so on.

In this way you can avoid multiple trips to the server and also no headache of managing that many variables in session. If you are making any decision based on first forms data and that decision can only be processed at the server end, then this is the best way.